# Django Admin not redirecting after loging in... Response is 200

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm developing an application using DRF and when I try  to login to my admin dashboard it gives

```
POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2350
```

but it doesn't redirect me to /admin. The strange thing is that everything worked yesterday. I'm also using React for the front-end and I have a sign-in page that uses `obtain_auth_token` from DRF. The Sign In page worked yesterday as well but today it doesn't.

I created a super user, made sure that the user has super user privileges and it still doesn't redirect me to the login page.
Here's my settings.py file
"""

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

import dj_database_url
import django_heroku

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'KEY'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'PaymentsApp.Account'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ]
}

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders',
    'PaymentsApp',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
    'http://localhost:3000'
)
# EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

# CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    'GET',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
    'PATCH',
    'DELETE',
    'OPTIONS'
)
ROOT_URLCONF = 'Payments.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Payments.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'payments',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5433',
    }
}
# db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500, ssl_require=True)
# DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static'),
]
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

I've tried deploying the app to Heroku today and it seems that this messed up something although I'm not quite sure. I have a backup that I made yesterday and that one doesn't work as well.
One more important thing to add, I have a custom Account model. Here it is:

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
        )

        user.set_password(make_password(password))
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
        )

        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    store_id = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Store ID", unique=True, default=0)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date joined", auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Last login", auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        created = not self.pk
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if created:
            AvailableAmount.objects.create(user=self, available_amount=0)


@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwards):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it. If you're using a custom user model make sure that you hash the password for the super user i.e. this won't work:

```
 def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password
        )

        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
```

and this is because the password isn't getting hashed and you won't be able to login. What you need to do is use `set_password` like this:

```
def create_superuser(self, email, password):
    user = self.create_user(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
    )

user.is_admin = True
user.is_staff = True
user.is_superuser = True
user.set_password(password)
user.save(using=self._db)
```

If this doesn't work for you, try to change your password from the console using `manage.py changepassword USERNAME`. If after changing you password you're able to log in, then there's a big chance that you don't hash the password on user creation.